# Is this a valid robots.txt file?

Tags: search, seo, robots.txt

I have this robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: *
Sitemap: Path_to_sitemap.xml
```

My Q is, should I have something else in there as well? Like allow All or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a valid robots.txt. You may read this post from google: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want ;-)
You don´t have to allow sth. special, just block the things you wouldn´t have crawled by Google and Co.